# How to parse a html string with structural directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to parse a html string with structural directive inside `ng-template`. But it is displayed as a string. My exceptions was the structural directive will iterate three times and it will show three `li`. How can I achieve that?

Here is my code

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = `<div><li *ngFor="let d of [1,2,3]">{{d}}</li> </div>`;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ html: data }"
  ></ng-container>
</section>

<ng-template #template let-html="html">
  {{ html }}
</ng-template>
```

[Sample code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tghb5l)

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you perform the interpolation on the controller itself, I don't think interpolation works on string insertion.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Sanitizer, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any = `<div>${[1, 2, 3].map((x) => `<li>${x}</li>`).join('')}</div>`;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.data);
  }
}
```

html

```
<section>
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ html: data }"
  ></ng-container>
</section>

<ng-template #template let-html="html" >
  <div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
</ng-template>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6bks2p)